# Test pull request in fork repo

Tags: git, github, git-branch, repo

I have fork my work repo, and was asked to review a pull request being added to the orgin repo. How can I test out the pull request in my fork repo?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the upstream repo set as a remote in git (and call it upstream), you can do

```
git pull upstream/branch
```

Obviously you will need to replace `branch` with the name of the PR branch, and I would recommend creating a new branch in your forked repository so that you don't affect your current working branch, but this should do exactly what you are looking for